# How to locate robot position on map using map -> base_link transform?

Tags: navigation, mapping, turtlebot, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running turtlebot in playground world and navigation

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_playground.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo gmapping_demo.launch
```

In my program code I successfully subscribe to /map topic and process its data as 2D array[height][width] of wall coordinates, but I'm unable to interpret results of

```
listener_.lookupTransform( "map", "base_link", ros::Time( 0 ), transform );
```

How to compare results of map array and map->base_link transform?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157726/how-to-locate-robot-position-on-map-using-map--%3E-base_link-transform?/) by [INait](https://answers.ros.org/users/11781/inait/) on ROS Answers with karma: 220 on 2014-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-05-05**:
Why we should compare the results? since it is giving relative robot position.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the answer myself.

I need to use map_metadata to get map configuration with the real world.

Cell where the robot situated is ( robot_position - map_origin ) / map_resolution, for x and y coordinates accordingly.

---

Originally posted by [INait](https://answers.ros.org/users/11781/inait/) with karma: 220 on 2014-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-04-28**:
Don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer.

**Comment by [INait](https://answers.ros.org/users/11781/inait/) on 2014-04-29**:
I don't have enough karma to do that.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-04-30**:
I took care of it for you. And you should have enough karma now.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-05-05**:
You are calculating robot position, but in your answer, you used again robot position??Can you please explain a little bit..I have posted a similar kind of question...http://answers.ros.org/question/161326/rosrun-tf-tf_echo-map-base_link-vs-coding-implementation/ .Please have a look....

**Comment by [INait](https://answers.ros.org/users/11781/inait/) on 2014-05-06**:
Sorry for late response, I see in your question that you found solution, is there something left uncleared?

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-05-06**:
@INait, now everything is ok..